# Did Michael Che really negotiate "four N words" for the 2018/19 season of SNL? He was not free to use the word whenever he saw fit?

Tags: comedy, saturday-night-live

At `00:59` in the 2018 SNL clip [Weekend Update: Really!?! with Seth Meyers, Colin Jost and Michael Che - SNL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pwRMXQRYRaw&t=59s) Michael Che begins a joke with:

> You know, I negotiated four N words this season in my new contract, that's true.

Yes he says "that's true" but this is SNL and Michael Che, so I'd like to ask:

**Question:** Did Michael Chen really negotiate "four N words" for the 2018/19 season of SNL? He was not free to use the word whenever he saw fit?

"Bonus points" for the other three.

[image: screenshot from "Weekend Update: Really!?! with Seth Meyers, Colin Jost and Michael Che - SNL" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pwRMXQRYRaw]

---

Comment: I've restored the saturday-night-live tag (which is already in use on ten other questions) because of course the question is about Che's performance during Saturday Night Live

Comment: It's not a show I've seen or a fact I would have any hope of tracking down, but the premise itself is loosely based on truth. There was a gag on UK TV maybe 25 years ago with a similar premise, "I'll trade you four bloodys for a f**k". In film/TV censorship, there was always something akin to an allotted number of times you could swear, to differing degrees, based on the general show content & intended audience. You could get away with one mild word early evening but a lot more later. The idea of trading for which words to use might be stretched, but a logical progression of the system.